# Unable to parse JSON response from wp_send_json_success

Tags: ajax, json

Trying to do this the WordPress way: `wp_send_json_success`

PHP processing `save_form` return:

```
        $response = array( 'messages' => $message );
        wp_send_json_success( $response );
```

jQuery:

```
        $j.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajax_url,
            data: {
                    action:         'save_form',
                    form_id:        $j('#form_id').val(),
                    full_name:      $j('#full_name').val(),
                    email:          $j('#email').val(),
                    signup_nonce:   $j('#signup_nonce').val()
                },
            success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.messages);
                },
            error: function (response) { }
        });
        return false;
```

Response in the Inspector:

```
JSON:
success: true
data: Object { messages: "Enter a valid email address" }
    messages: "Enter a valid email address"
```

but...

```
console.log(response.messages);
```

returns nothing.

What am I missing?

Thanks, Brad

Comment: As asked by Sally, can you help edit the code to include the `alert("Hello")` statement?
Also `response.data.messages` should be used to get the desired data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you should use `response.data.messages`.

And that's because [`wp_send_json_success()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/) will send a JSON response (an object) with the property `data` set to whatever that you passed to the function.

```php
wp_send_json_success( 123 );
// In JS, response.data would be an integer. I.e. response.data = 123

wp_send_json_success( array( 'foo' => 'bar' ) );
// In JS, response.data would be an object. So response.data.foo = 'bar'
```

Comment: Tried that @Sally CJ, but it's not getting past the `success: function (response)`. I stuck an `alert("Hello")` on the next line and nothing. Not sure what this is but the Response Payload:
`1    2 string(0) ""    3 {"success":true,"data":{"messages":"Enter a valid email"}};`

Comment: Try adding `dataType: 'json'` to the `$j.ajax()` args. But where is `alert()` in your code?

Comment: Insert embarrassment emoji. There was a stray `var_dump` in the PHP,  hence the `string(0)`. Through the old trick of commenting out halves of code, I found it. I used to see this in my old Perl debugging. Anyway, now works as advertised. `dataType` is not needed, the response header clearly shows `json` Sorry for the trouble.